# Python - read, write and append to a file

Tags: python, file, file-io, python-3.x

I am new to python. In a file there are different port numbers. I want to iterate through the port number. The ports are separated by comma. And at the end I want to append my port number in that file. The code I have written is not working as there always is a newline at the end. How can I solve this problem. And is there a better solution. Here is my code -

```
        f = open("ports.txt", "r")
        line = f.readline()
        line = line.split(",")
        print(line)

        if len(line) > 0:
            del line[-1]
        for port in line:
            print(port)
        f = open("ports.txt", "a")
        m = str(self.myPort)+","
        f.write(m)
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# read port-list
with open('ports.txt') as inf:
    ports = [int(i) for line in inf for i in line.split(',')]

# display ports
for port in ports:
    print(port)

# recreate file
ports.append(myPort)
ports.sort()
with open('ports.txt', 'w') as outf:
    outf.write(','.join(str(p) for p in ports))
```

Comment: thank you for your generous comment. I am sorry to ask this but what does " ports = [int(i) for line in inf for i in line.split(',')] " mean?

Comment: @eddard.stark: for each line in the ports.txt file, it splits out the comma-separated numbers and converts each to an integer. It then returns all of them in a list.

Comment: it's better to use the methods of the csv module for extracting the values rather than reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with comma separated values, you should in general use the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

The code below should be pretty self-explanatory.

```
import csv

# By using the with statement, you don't have to worry about closing the file
# for reading/writing. This is taken care of automaticly.
with open('ports.txt') as in_file:
    # Create a csv reader object from the file object. This will yield the
    # next row every time you call next(reader)
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)

    # Put the next(reader) statement inside a try ... except block. If the
    # exception StopIteratorion is raised, there is no data in the file, and
    # an IOError is raised.
    try:
        # Use list comprehension to convert all strings to integers. This 
        # will make sure no leading/trailing whitespace or any newline 
        # character is printed to the file
        ports = [int(port) for port in next(reader)]
    except StopIteration:
        raise IOError('No data in file!')

with open('ports.txt', 'wb') as out_file:
    # Create a csv writer object
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    # Append your port to the list of ports...
    ports.append(self.myPort)
    # ...and write the data to the csv file
    writer.writerow(ports)
```